# Best way to stop sibling components reacting to keyboard events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, keyboard, dom-events

I'm using React and React-bootstrap and I have a series of movable boxes which can be moved by the mouse, but I would also like to be able to adjust them with the keyboard.

My architecture is something like this (simplified for this example):

```
<parentImg>
  [<childMovableBox ref='box1'>,
   <childMovableBox ref='box2'>,
   <childMovableBox ref='box3'>,
   <childMovableBox ref='box4'>]
</parentImg>
```

Each time the user clicks the parent img, another box is created. I would like only the last "interacted with" (either created or moved by mouse) `childMovableBox` to react to the arrow keys.

---

Q1: How do I make the target of the keyboard presses the last "interacted with" `childMovableBox`?

- Do I add a keyboard eventhandler for each `childMoveableBox` and give each component focus whenever its ComponentDidUpdate
  is called?
- What do I give focus to? Its top level div (in render)?
  or something else?
- Do I need the `tabIndex=0` on each `childMoveableBox`?
- I would like the `childMoveableBox` to also get keyboard presses when *its* children have focus. How do I achieve that?

---

Q2: All my `childMoveableBox`'s are the same component with differenet ref's (and keys) so how to I make sure only the correct `childMoveableBox` (and not its siblings) reacts to the keyboard press?

*I believe that they all will get the keyboard event because of the way that event capturing works by moving down the dom tree (from `parentImg` to all children of `parentImg`) and then back up from the target (focused `childMoveableDiv` back up through `parentImg`?).*

---

There's a bunch of questions here, maybe I should split them into different posts?

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow. I think I fixed my issue. I was adding an event handler using the `document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKey, false);` method, and not reacts built in `onKeyPress={this.somefunction}` method. 
The react way does what I want, so it guess react has a slightly different order of event capturing (where last interacted with child is given event first?) which then allows me to use event.stopPropagation to stop it going to other siblings?